# BazaarVoice and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, sdk, google-analytics, tracking, event-tracking

I recently noticed that our Google Analytics integration with BazaarVoice stopped sending events to our analytics tracking. It worked fine until November 1st. We still use the old Google Analytics since BazaarVoice doesn't support Universal Analytics yet. I tried to investigate why no BazaarVoice events appear in GA but without success.

**Has anybody experienced similar problems or has a solid understanding of BazaarVoice and Google Analytics ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I'm a Developer Advocate at Bazaarvoice. Could you open a ticket with our Support team at https://bazaarvoice.secure.force.com/cp/cplogin? If it's Bazaarvoice related they will be able to help you.

Comment: @frederickf Thank you. I registered an account. I hope your Support can help us out :) I'll post the solution if possible.